# Using yield in callback?

Tags: php, callback, generator, yield

I have a function `y()` that is supposed to yield some records.

This function however obtains the records within a callback which is passed to another function `d()` to access the data.
`d()` does not return or yield anything.

Is this pattern possible if that other function `d()` that accepts the callback is considered a black box?
What would be an alternative design?

```
function y() {
    d( function ($records) { // May be called multiple times
        // How to yield for "y()"?
        foreach ($records as $record)
            yield $record;
    } );
}
```

Comment: Using callbacks is an unusual pattern for synchronous programming to begin with. Or is this code supposed to be asynchronous is any way?

Comment: It could be considered asynchronous in some way, or rather interleaved, which is why `yield` is applicable - `d()` performs some initialization, invokes the callback, possibly multiple times, and does some cleanup afterwards, and cannot be unfolded / broken up, e.g. because it is a PHP native/extension function or from a third-party library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `yield` turns the anonymous callback function into a generator function. You'd need to call this generator function to receive a generator and then iterate over that generator. But since `d` is calling the anonymous function, it's the one that ends up with the generator, not the caller of `y`. So this is of little use and in fact does not work.

It seems the best you can do is this:

```
function y() {
    $results = [];
    d(function ($val) use (&$results) {
        $results[] = $val;
    });
    return $results;
}

foreach (y() as $val) {
    echo $val, PHP_EOL;
}
```

This of course depends on  `d` returning at some point. If internally it uses an endless loop, this won't do any good. In that case you'd need to keep calling further callbacks from within your callback, which is a typical event listener pattern.